# Generating random "break points" in a sequence a minimum distance from each other

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a sequence with `n` elements, where I would like to *randomly* place `k` "break points" each at least `minDist` away from each other (and the ends). Example, for `n=9, k=2, minDist=2`, I want to generate one of following with equal probability:

```
[2 4][2 5][2 6][2 7][3 5][3 6][3 7][4 6][4 7][5 7]
```

So far I've come up with: placing one randomly, "disabling" the required amount of nodes around it, then picking another random number, but this strikes me as slightly unefficient. I'm programming in MATLAB, but any language is fine.

I will be using this to initialize the population for some genetic algorithms, so I would like to have each of the possabilities equally likely, to ensure I'm covering the whole search space. Just deterministically distributing the break points is not good enough.

Comment: what is the `[3,7]` in your example?

Comment: Is `[3,7]` the required location of the breakpoints? If so, how does specifying that interact with also requiring a `minDist`?

Comment: You gave a really confusing example dude.

Comment: @LuisMendo The example was confusing, [3 7] is one of the results I would like to generate. I've clarified the example, hopefully now it's more understandable.

Comment: @VPeric In your example if `minDist==2` and your elements ar enumbered 1 to 9, then you shouldn't have 2 in your breakbpoints, shouldn't the smallest be 3.

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia The notation is, breakpoint after the given number, so 2 is ok. If I'd change it to "before", then I'd have to include 8 also.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that generates all possible breakpoint combinations, you can store them in a list instead of printing them, and then uniformly choose one of them:

```
static void breakpointCombinations(List<int> possiblePositions, List<int> breakpointCombination, int remainingBreakpoints, int minSpace, int currentPos)
{
    if (remainingBreakpoints == 0)
    {
        foreach (int tempPos in breakpointCombination)
        {
            Console.Write(tempPos + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    else if (remainingBreakpoints * minSpace > possiblePositions.Count - currentPos)
        return;

    else
    {
        if (currentPos >= minSpace - 1)
        {
            breakpointCombination.Add(possiblePositions[currentPos]);
            breakpointCombinations(possiblePositions, breakpointCombination, remainingBreakpoints - 1, minSpace, currentPos + minSpace);
            breakpointCombination.Remove(possiblePositions[currentPos]);
        }

        breakpointCombinations(possiblePositions, breakpointCombination, remainingBreakpoints, minSpace, currentPos + 1);
    }
}
```

The call for the function (in this example, 10 elements, 2 breakpoints, with minimal space of 2):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> Positions = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Positions.Add(i);
    }

    breakpointCombinations(Positions, new List<int>(), 2, 2, 0);
}
```

It was implied from you example that a space of 2 means that there should be at least one position between 2 breakpoints (which mean [2, 4] is legit for example), I treated the spaces from the beginning and end the same one (this wasn't consistent in the example), which mean if the elements are [0, ... ,9], the first legit breakpoint is at element 1 and the last at element 8.

Comment: Its not exactly matlab, but the underlying algorithm was my first thought as well. Especially if the number of pairs you want to select is (much) greater than the number of possible pairs, this should be efficient.

Comment: I'm numbering my elements from 1-9, and the breakpoint is "after" the given position. What's inconsistent in my example? First legal position is 2 (so elements 1 and 2 are before the breakpoint) and last legal position is 7 (so elements 8 and 9 are after the breakpoint).

Comment: @VPeric I didn't understand from you definition that the first breakpoint excludes the first element (could have been before that element for that matter...). anyway it's semantics, the algorithm should do the work (change the the `else if` comparison to `>=`).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having random (but small) computation time, you can use a *rejection method*:

1. Randomly generate tentative break points with uniform distribution;
2. Check if they satisfy your restrictions;
3. Repeat if they don't.

This assures an equal probability for each valid combination of break points, without having to generate all those combinations initially.

In Matlab:

```
done = 0;
while ~done
  breakPoints = sort(randi(n,1,k));
  done = all(diff([0 breakPoints n]) >= minDist);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your specification you could just start from the left and place breakpoints `k-1` times after every `minDist` elements.

You have to revise your spec if you want your divisions to be more *uniformly* distributed.

Comment: Thanks, I agree my initial question was confusing. Regardless, I would like all possibilities to be equally likely, so just distributing the break points like this is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want to cover the entire search space, you should not pick random points.

Instead you should pick all points, perhaps in a random order.

Here is a simple way to pick all the points for `k = 2`:

```
n=9;
minDist = 2;
p = [];
for x = minDist:n-minDist*2
   for y = x+minDist:n-minDist
     p = [p;x y]
   end
end
```

For low values of k you can simply add nested loops.

Once you have all the points, picking them randomly should be trivial.

Comment: I'd rather avoid writing nested for cycles; not that any solution is not going to degenerate to this, but just for purposes of portability.

Comment: @VPeric If you basically want the functionality that I offer, but allowing for an arbitrary k, then try looking into recursion. In general that is the automated way to nest for loops.